# How do I add an api to server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I added an api controller to the project and changed the startup file. But still not working

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeApiController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/HomeApi
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

}
```

and

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "api",
    template: "api/{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: What url do you try to access this api by? Notice the difference between the attribute route and route config.

Comment: @Emad, /api/Home/Get - link, I get 404 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route attribute on the controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HomeApiController : ControllerBase
```

will map to

```
api/homeapi
```

because of the name of the controller replaced by the `[controller]` token in the route template.

rename the controller accordingly

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
```

Or update the route template

```
[Route("api/home")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeApiController : ControllerBase
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)